# NextJS saying that there is a syntax error when using build

Tags: next.js, syntax-error, node-modules, unexpected-token, npm-build

I am attempting to use NextJS and I am run the command npm run build but it says next command cant be found. I re-install next globally this time (npm i -g next) and the net command is found but is then throwing an error saying "unexpected token '?'"

The complete error is:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:440
                    ...pageKeys.app ?? []
                                     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-build.js:15:55)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
```

I have attached a photo of all of the context if that helps.

[Photo of the error plus context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXsJj.png)

I have tried to install next globally by adding -g to the npm install command and it fixed the first step of the problem I guess which was the next command not being found but then created another problem as stated previously. I am expecting Tovy to completely build but it can't because of the error.